# Searching chat history in Skype For Business

Tags: skype, chat, skype-for-business

I had chat conversations (text) with my friend Adam 50 times over the past 200 days. Skype for Business does not collate all these conversations into one conversation across time. Instead, I literally have 50 separate conversations.

I would like to search all the 50 conversations I had with Adam. How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look to your outlook mailbox. It may contain a folder with all your Skype for business conversations in it.

Comment: It's the only solution as far as I can see because Skype Bussiness does not let you search in chats.